# javascript function doesn't return any result

Tags: javascript

I've got a javascript function

```
<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetResult()
        {
            count = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
                for(var j=1;j<4;j++){
                    if (document.getElementById("label"+i+j).checked){
                        count +=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count!=10)
                alert("Please answer all the questions");
            else alert(count);
        }
    </script>
```

In the code there are a lot of radiobutton. ther look like

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="label01"/>
```

But my javascript function never shows alert. 
The button that is supposed to call function is

```
<input type="button" value="Result" onclick="GetResult()"/>
```

Maybe button doesn't call `GetResult`?

Comment: Do you get any error? If the element with ID `"label"+i+j` does not exist, `document.getElementById("label"+i+j).checked` will throw an error (since `getElementById` will return `null`).

Comment: It's getting an error at the spot where Felix King pointed out and thus doesn't finish.  You need some kind of check to make sure it's not null.

Comment: hm.it is null. what is wrong?I can't check if radiobutton is checked like this?

Comment: probably it isn't returning anything because you don't have any `return` in your function?

Comment: @user1432980 Yes, you normally can do that the way you're trying. But you're testing more labels than you've got on your page, hence the error when trying to find the missing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate what Felix already said: Here is how you can check whether or not `document.getElementById` found the specified element (it will return null if it failed).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        // Store the result in a local variable
        var label = document.getElementById("label"+i+j);

        // Include a check whether "null" got returned
        if (label && label.checked) {
            count +=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function GetResult() {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++){
                var label = document.getElementById("label" + i + j);
                if (label && label.checked) {
                    count +=1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count != 10) {
            alert("Не все отвечено");
        } else {
            alert(count);
        }
    }
```

- Added `var` to the `count` declaration.
- Fixed up some general formatting.
- The important bit: checked to see if `document.getElementById()` returned a value before checking that value's `checked` property.